# Set div with certain class to be same height as window innerHeight

Tags: javascript

So, this seems easy enough to do in my head, but I can't get it to work and Google isn't helping me, can you see what I'm doing wrong?

I have 5 divs, I want them to be the same height as the browser window. Even on resize.

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function setDivHeight(){
    var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
    if(windowHeight > 400){
        document.getElementsByClassName("minHeight").style.backgroundColor = 'black';
    }
    else if(windowHeight < 400){
        document.getElementsByClassName("minHeight").style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    }
}

window.addEventListener("resize",setDivHeight,false);
</script>
</head>
<style type="text/css">

body{margin:0; padding:0;}

.minHeight{
    height:20px;
}

.a{
    background: #09C;
}
.b{
    background: #09b;
}
.c{
    background: #09d;
}
.d{
    background: #09e;
}
.e{
    background: #09f;
}



</style>
<body onload="setDivHeight()">
<div class="a minHeight"></div>
<div class="b minHeight"></div>
<div class="c minHeight"></div>
<div class="d minHeight"></div>
<div class="e minHeight"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try my answer. Is that you needed?

Comment: An answer to your question you can find at [MDN: NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/NodeList), since `nodeList` is what `getElementsByClassName()` returns.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use javascript for this. Check the [**JSFiddle DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/NjrnY/)

Check the following code

**HTML**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <body>
        <div class="a minHeight"></div>
        <div class="b minHeight"></div>
        <div class="c minHeight"></div>
        <div class="d minHeight"></div>
        <div class="e minHeight"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
html{height:100%}
body{margin:0; padding:0;height:100%;}
.minHeight{
    height:100%;
    width: 40px;
}
.a{
    background-color: #09C;
}
.b{
    background-color: #09b;
}
.c{
    background-color: #09d;
}
.d{
    background-color: #09e;
}
.e{
    background-color: #09f;
}

div{float: left;}
```

Answer (score 1):

so u want that the `div`'s are the same size as your screen?
`position: absolute; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px;`

Comment: Thanks @akehorn, but I've got MULTIPLE divs, so this will not work.

Comment: so all the divs must be displayed at the same time in one window?

Comment: @akehorn This solution is still valid, regardless of the amount of divs you have in your page. You just need to modify the style attribute of your divs and set it to this.